# grub issue due to removal of windows partition

Tags: grub2

I recently installed Windows 7 on Ubuntu and used EasyBCD (in windows) to manage the grub. After deleting the windows partition, I am unable to login to Ubuntu since at startup, I am stuck with the boot menu created by EasyBCD which doesn't work now.

Any ideas or suggestions? Thanks in anticipation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to boot from any linux distro live cd eg. Ubuntu and then mount the partitions and install grub (XY will be different in your case):

```
sudo mount -t ext4 /dev/sdXY /mnt
```

if you need to see how to mount other filesystem please see :

```
man mount
```

mount your filesystem and bind to the directories

```
sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev &&
sudo mount --bind /dev/pts /mnt/dev/pts &&
sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc &&
sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
```

change the root :

```
sudo chroot /mnt
```

Now your can run install and update grub using (name sdX should be different in your case) :

```
grub-install /dev/sdX
grub-install --recheck /dev/sdX
update-grub
```

Now exit chroot, unmount and reboot and it should work.

Comment: thank you. I'll try your advice.